# python program to extract unique IP addresses and save into another file

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract unique IP addresses from a snort log file and store them in a separated file. If it exists then just ignore it. But the output shows repeated IP addresses as well. How do I prevent this?

This is my code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
lst = []
lst2 = []
lstb = []
logfile = open('/var/log/snort/alllogs', 'r')
blist = open('blacklist', 'ab+')
for lines in logfile.readlines():
 lines = lines.rstrip()
 badip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}',lines)
 if badip is not None and badip not in lst:
   lst.append(badip)
for ip in lst:
  addr = ",".join(ip)
 if ',' in addr:
   s = addr.split(',')
    for ip in s:
        addr = "".join(ip)
        if addr is not '':
            lst2.append(addr)
        else:
            if addr is not '':
                lst2.append(addr)
for i in blist:
  lst2.append(i.strip())
for i in lst2:
  if i not in lstb:
    blist.write(i+'\n')'
```

The result is:

```
192.168.12.10
192.168.1.120
192.168.1.120
192.168.12.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of duplicates in the list with this one liner:

```
lst2 = list(set(lst2))
```

I don't see where you fill lstb, that's probably why your solution doesn't work.

If you want fix for your solution consider something like this:

```
for i in lst2:
      if i not in lstb:
        blist.write(i+'\n')
        lstb.append(i)
```

Comment: I was just missed it. too bad
thank you giliev in advance

Comment: @RAZHamraz you should accept the answer if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Sure it fixed giliev but when i run the program again, it adds duplicated IP addresses to the blacklist file.

Output after first program run:
    cat blacklist
    192.168.12.10
    192.168.1.120

Output after second program run:
    cat blacklist
    192.168.12.10
    192.168.1.120
    192.168.12.10
    192.168.1.120

I just stuck what I have missed here☹

Comment: You will need to read the IP addresses from your output file and add them to lstb (or some other list/set). After that *if i not in lstb:* will detect that you already have that IP address.

Comment: Thank you in advance giliev.

Comment: I've modified the code as bellow to read the blacklist file and avoid if IP already exists but it is not detecting. what should I do now giliev? here is the modification:

    blist = open('blacklist', 'ab+') 
    mylist = open("blacklist", "r")
    already = mylist.readlines()
.
.
.
 if i not in lstb and i not in already:
        blist.write(i+'\n')
        lstb.append(i)

blacklist file output (after second running the program):
    192.168.12.10
    192.168.1.120
    192.168.1.110
    192.168.12.120
I want it should be detected in the same program not in separated one.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking :

```
if i not in lstb
```

but lstb is never used in your code.

Comment: You're right, of course, but why on earth hadn't the OP done some really really simple debugging and discovered this themselves? It's just too easy to post a question and sit back waiting for someone else to tell you what's wrong, and then the poster doesn't learn how to debug. Sigh.

Comment: yeah you right. but sometime people just stuck barny